# How to troubleshoot Windows 10 backup that fails silently

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup

I've configured Windows 10 Backup to backup to a local disk, F:.  The disk is formatted and empty, except for the folders that Backup has created.  Windows says that nothing is backed up yet, but when I click on "Back up now" it changes to "backing up your data" briefly and then goes back to "your data is not backed up."

I've confirmed that File History Service is running, and I've restarted Windows entirely.

I don't see anything relevant in Event Viewer under Critical, Error, or Warning.

How can I troubleshoot further?

[image]

Comment: Windows Backup is very quirky, I suggest using a third-party product such as in [this link](https://doakio.com/blog/best-free-file-based-backup-program-gizmos-freeware-archive/).